# NLog: LayoutRenderer cannot be found

Tags: nlog

NLog throws an exception while trying to create logger:

```
var configuration = new XmlLoggingConfiguration(configurationPath);

Exception message: LayoutRenderer cannot be found: 'TargetDirectory'
```

Logger configuration:

```
<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <extensions>
    <add assembly="NLog.Extended" />
  </extensions>
  <variables>
    <variable name="TargetDirectory" 
              value="D:\Internal\Logs\" />
...
  <targets>
    <target name="TraceLog"
            xsi:type="File"
            fileName="${TargetDirectory}${TraceLogname}"
...
</nlog>
```

`NLog.Extended.dll` is presented in `bin` folder
`D:\Internal\Logs\` folder exists on HDD but I don't think that it is the problem's root

But what?

Answer (score 2):

Change `value="D:\Internal\Logs\"`

to:

`value="D:/Internal/Logs/"`

**and**

`fileName="${TargetDirectory}${TraceLogname}`

to:

`fileName="${TargetDirectory}/${TraceLogname}`